# Search through json with user input python

Tags: python, json

This is the json https://pastebin.com/2Z2DZ4Y6. I want to be able to use user input to search for tags and to send the gfyId. This is the code I have so far but I'm not sure if it helps. If I were to enter "jihyo" it would send random gfyId with that tag. Or if I were to enter "dahyun instagram" it would send a random gfyId with both of those tags. I want it to search for all gfyId's that fit the arguments and send a random one. I'm pretty new to coding so if someone could help or point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.gfycat.com/v1/users/jukebaet/gfycats?"

r = requests.get(url, params=pram)

text_json = json.loads(r.content)

for g in text_json["gfycats"]:
    tags = (g["tags"])
    gfyid = (g["gfyId"])
    print(str(tags) + " " + gfyid)

json.dump(text_json, open("testdump.json", "w"), indent = 2)
```

Comment: try something and let us know where you get stuck

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, don't share the JSON on pastebin, it's best to keep questions as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may ask content to the user and split on space to get the words. The use of `set` allows to use `issubset` to check if all words are included in the tags of the current element form the loop, if it matches save it in a list

```
tags = set(input('What tags are looking for ? ').split(" "))
gfyids = []
for g in text_json["gfycats"]:
    if tags.issubset(set(g["tags"])):
        gfyids.append(g['gfyId'])
```

---

Example

```
What tags are looking for ? dahyun instagram
['slowmalegrayreefshark', 'severenaivebluetickcoonhound']

What tags are looking for ? jihyo
['anyignoranthorsefly']
```

Comment: Thank you for the help